# Can't Select Text in Safari

Tags: javascript, events, safari, dojo

Interesting problem here.

After upgrading to Dojo 1.6, in Safari, I can't select any text via left click.  No text is highlighted.

Can still highlight text inside a content-editable div, however, no other text is highlighting.  Sometimes, the left-click highlight magically starts working again (haven't determined what the cause there is).

Anyone seen this/have a theory how Safari would stop respecting left-click to highlight text?

As if ... someone added a onclick handler that returns false to the `<body>` tag.  But that doesn't appear to be the case (its a large app), and other browsers are OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

webkit has a CSS rule called user-select. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

So is something setting this somewhere?

```
-webkit-user-select: none
```

Check the computed style in your inspector to see if that is being set.